# Laravel 5 query builder restrict

Tags: laravel-5

I have 3 tables: `candidate`, `position` and `recruitmentform`. `Candidateid` and `positionid` are foreign keys in the `recruitmentform` table.

I'm trying to implement that when a candidate applies for a position which he already applied to, he shouldn't be able to. I tried something like this but it's not working.

```
$check = DB::table('recruitmentform')->select('positionid')->where('candidateid',$cid)->get();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($check); $i++) {
        if ($check[$i] == $pid) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get column by name from array element

```php
$check = DB::table('recruitmentform')
    ->select('positionid')
    ->where('candidateid',$cid)
    ->get();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($check); $i++) {
    if ($check[$i]->positionid == $pid) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

But loops reduces the performance of the application. So try to avoid loops as much as possible. you can use following to get the same result without a loop

```php
$application = DB::table('recruitmentform')
    ->where('candidateid', $cid)
    ->where('positionid', $pid)
    ->first();

if (!is_null($application)) {
    return redirect()->to('/');
}
```